# Node.js cross-platform terminal app

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-platform, node-webkit

I need to create simple cross-platform (Linux, Win, OSX) terminal application with node.js. I think the best and simplest way is to create npm package with cli script, but my app should be standalone. First I've come to solution: for Win and OSX - create installer with bundled node.js binary and for Linux - create packages with nodejs as dependency, imho it's too complicated for ~300 LOC app. Currently I'm using node-webkit with "window": {"show": false} in package.json and must be reconciled with completely unnecessary webkit engine packaged in my app binary.
Maybe there is an easier way to create cross-platform cli apps with node?
Thanks for help!

Comment: If the users don't already have node installed then...nope.  And if you took this route, what happens if the user already has a copy of node installed?  Now they potentially have two?  I think if you need a cross-platform app, you might look at Java or Go as both seem better suited to the task?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've chosen an npm package.